# How to get audio stream from node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream

i'm trying to stream a mp3 from a node.js server but i cannot receive any data, or, if i refresh my client page i get a cross origin error

my server code is this:

```
fs.readFile(path, function(error, file) {
    if (error) {
        response.writeHead(500, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
        response.write(error + "\n");
        response.end();
    } else {
        console.log('file ok');

        var stat = fs.statSync(path);
        var total = stat.size;
        console.log('video size: ' + total);
        var origin = (request.headers.origin || "*");
        if (request.headers['range']) {
            var range = request.headers.range;
            console.log('range: ' + range);
            var parts = range.replace(/bytes=/, "").split("-");
            console.log('parts: ' + parts);
            var partialstart = parts[0];
            console.log('partialstart: ' + partialstart);
            var partialend = parts[1];
            console.log('partialend: ' + partialend);

            var start = parseInt(partialstart, 10);
            var end = partialend ? parseInt(partialend, 10) : total - 1;
            var chunksize = (end-start) + 1;
            console.log('RANGE: ' + start + ' - ' + end + ' = ' + chunksize);

            var fileStr = fs.createReadStream(path, {start: start, end: end});
            response.writeHead(
                "200",
                "OK",
                {
                    "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": true,
                    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": origin,
                    "Content-Type": 'audio/mp3',
                    "Access-Control-Max-Age": 60*60*24*365, // Seconds.
                    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET,PUT,POST,DELETE",
                    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Content-Type",
                    "Content-Range": "bytes " + start + "-" + end + "/" + total,
                    "Accept-Ranges": "bytes",
                    "Content-Length": chunksize
                }
            );
            //response.writeHead(206, { 'Content-Range': 'bytes ' + start + '-' + end + '/' + total, 'Accept-Ranges': 'bytes', 'Content-Length': chunksize, 'Content-Type': 'audio/mpeg' });
            fileStr.pipe(response);
        } else {
            console.log('ALL: ' + total);
            response.writeHead(
                "200",
                "OK",
                {
                    "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": true,
                    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": origin,
                    "Content-Type": "audio/mp3",
                    "Content-Length": file.length,
                    "Access-Control-Max-Age": 60*60*24*365, // Seconds.
                    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET,PUT,POST,DELETE",
                    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Content-Type"
                }
            );
            fs.createReadStream(path).pipe(response);
            //response.end(html);
            response.end(html);
            console.log('-end-');
        }
    }
});
```

i always arrive to -end- but no data is arriving on the client..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Media streaming module for node.JS and JXcore .. https://github.com/obastemur/mediaserver

You can either use it or check the source codes.